# exclude multiple terms using get_terms() function

Tags: php, functions, categories

I am using this function to filter category terms from a calendar:

```
  $terms = get_terms( TribeEvents::TAXONOMY, array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC','exclude' => array(77)) );

  echo '<li>Category:</li>';
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?tribe_eventcategory='.$term->term_taxonomy_id.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
  }
```

I need to exclude event category ID 71 too. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the term with ID 71 part of the `TribeEvents::TAXONOMY` or is it a term under the standard `category` taxonomy?

Comment: I am not sure, What you mean but we need to remove the category with id 71 just same as we did with category with id 77.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), the `exclude` parameter takes an array of term IDs, so just add the second term to the array:

```
$terms = get_terms( TribeEvents::TAXONOMY, array( 
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'order'   => 'ASC',
                        'exclude' => array( 77, 71 ),
) );

echo '<li>Category:</li>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?tribe_eventcategory='.$term->term_taxonomy_id.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the same by due to typo  it was missing one closing bracket. It's fixed thank you :)